# predefined routing is not working cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

after I have installed a new LAMP Server I wanted to install cakephp3 on my server. So far everything works fine. I have generated the scaffold code explained in the beginner tutorial. After the code has been successfully generated I have noticed that the standard routing is not working, so I cannot call actions from controller, for example by typing http://adress/cakephp/Users/add. Instead of a error message occurs 
"The requested URL /cakephp/Bookmarks was not found on this server."

This is irritating me, because I have also a MAMP Server on my MAC with a installed cakephp application and I didnt have errors like this. Thank you.

Comment: $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute'); is responsible for the predefined routes. it is also added in routes.php, but has no effect.

Comment: Is the error message shown by your webserver or cakephp? If by webserver then issue is url rewriting, you probably missed a .htaccess file. If by cakephp then turn on debug so that you get detailed error message.

Comment: Also check the casing in your URLs. You should use `/bookmarks` not `/Bookmarks`.

Comment: .htaccess is in / , /src and /webroot. but it is still not working.